# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13 "Integrals", Problem 11b: Which functions have the property that some upper sum equals some (other) lower sum?

Tags: calculus, integration

The following is a problem from chapter 13 "Integrals" of Spivak's Calculus

> 11. (a) Which functions have the property that every lower sum equals every upper sum?
>
> (b) Which functions have the property that some upper
> sum equals some (other) lower sum?

$L(f,P)$ is the lower sum of $f$ for a partition $P$, and $U(f,P)$ is the upper sum of $f$ for a partition $P$. For a partition $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$, $m_i=\inf\{f(x): t_{i-1}\leq x \leq t_i\}$ and $M_i=\sup\{f(x): t_{i-1}\leq x \leq t_i\}$

Here is the solution manual solution

> (a) If $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ for even one partition $P$, then each
> $m_i=M_i$, so $f$ is constant on each $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. Since these
> closed intervals overlap, $f$ must be constant on all of $[a,b]$.
>
> (b) If $L(f,P_1)=U(f,P_2)$ and $P$ contains both $P_1$ and $P_2$, then
> $L(f,P_1) \leq L(f,P) \leq U(f,P) \leq U(f,P_2)=L(f,P_1)$, so
> $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$. It follows from part (a) that $f$ is constant on
> $[a,b]$.

**My question regards part $(b)$.**

Consider the following scenario. $f$ is composed of multiple intervals in which it is constant. The green lines represent a partition $P_1$, and the red lines represent another partition $P_2$. The lower and upper sums are the same for $P_1$ and $P_2$, but the function is not constant.

**Is this not a counterexample to the conclusion reached by the solution manual that $f$ is constant?**

[image]

The solution manual says that since $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$. But $P$ doesn't represent every partition. It represents partitions that contain $P_1$ and $P_2$. In the context of the picture above, this means any partition that adds more vertical lines to the red and green ones already present in the picture above.

Comment: Keep in mind that the upper and lower sums are defined using the inf and sup of the function on the *closed* intervals of the partition. The lower and upper sums are not the same for $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: If $P_1=\{t_0,t_1,...,t_8\}$ and $P_2=\{t_0,t_2, t_4, t_6, t_8\}$ (imagine that $t_0$ to $t_8$ correspond to the y-axis plus the first eight vertical light green and red lines in the picture, ie the first two constant portions of $f$). You seem to be implying that at $t_4$, $f$ takes on either the value of the first horizontal portion or the value of the second horizontal portion of its graph. Assume, for example, that at $t_4$ the value of $f$ is that of the first horizontal portion. Then, the partition subinterval $[t_4, t_5]$ of $P_1$, or $[t_4, t_6]$ of $P_2$ is such that

Comment: the lower sum differs from the upper sum. So the picture does not, then, represent a counterexample.

Comment: The question still remains, however, about the proof provided by the solution manual. How do they invoke the result for part $(a)$ when the assumption used is that $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ not for every single possible partition $P$, but only for every single one containing $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: Since $P$ is a refinement of both $P_k$s you have $L(f,P_1) \leq L(f,P) \leq U(f,P) \leq U(f,P_2)=L(f,P_1)$. That is, there is a partition $P$ such that $L(f,P) = U(f,P)$ and so $f$ must be a constant.

Comment: Notice that the solution for part (a) covers the case where $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ for *one* partition.